# Column and Row Indexing - VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to write something that does the following in excel macro (VBA):

```
For 'column X' of 'spreadsheet'
     Copy range(row(1):row(5)
     Paste to 'other spreadsheet' in range (row(1):row(5)) and column(Y)
```

And I want that to loop through the first spreadsheet for every column in the spreadsheet. This is what I have for 1 column:

```
Sheets("Info").Range("B3:B6").Value = Worksheets("Temp").Range("HK5:HK8").Value

  Sheets("Info").Range("C3:C6").Value = Worksheets("Temp").Range("HK10:HK13").Value
```

This is what I want to do, however for every column within the first spreadsheet (there is 300 columns, manually would be tedious).

**EDIT: This is another way i have found that may help explain the comments left below:**

```
For i = 2 To 3
    Worksheets("Info").Range(Cells(3, i), Cells(6, i)).Value = Worksheets("Temp").Range(Cells(5, i), Cells(8, i)).Value
Next i
```

I hoping this loops over the columns (2 - 290) currently its only from column 2 to 3 for testing purposes. I want the cells from TEMP worksheet from every column ('i') from row 5-8 and I want to put that into the INFO worksheet in column ('i') rows 3-6. Hope this helps!

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to achieve. Take data from column HK in sheet "Temp" and split it into multiple columns in sheet "Info" ? How do you define the range you want to work with ? row(1:5); range("B3:B6");range("HK5:HK8") ? How do you increment rows in column HK ?

Comment: Record a macro that does what you want - and show the code. Repeat again and show the code. Agree with @J.Doe - your pseudo code doesn't match your description

Answer (score 0):

Your description isn't consistent and I am not sure what is wrong with your final code. I have left a commented out debug statement so you can see what ranges are being worked with.

But

1. Use Option Explicit at the top of your code
2. Make sure to declare i as Long
3. Switch of ScreenUpdating to speed up performance
4. Use variables to hold the worksheets
5. Fully qualify `Cells` references with their worksheet

   ```
   Public Sub test()

   Dim i As Long
   Dim wsInfo As Worksheet
   Dim wsTemp As Worksheet
   Set wsInfo = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Info")
   Set wsTemp = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Temp")

   Application.ScreenUpdating = False
   For i = 2 To 290
      ' Debug.Print wsInfo.Name & "!" & wsInfo.Range(wsInfo.Cells(3, i), wsInfo.Cells(6, i)).Address & " = " & wsTemp.Name & "!" & wsTemp.Range(wsTemp.Cells(5, i), wsTemp.Cells(8, i)).Address
       wsInfo.Range(wsInfo.Cells(3, i), wsInfo.Cells(6, i)).Value = wsTemp.Range(wsTemp.Cells(5, i), wsTemp.Cells(8, i)).Value
   Next i
   Application.ScreenUpdating = True
   End Sub
   ```